# Autosys Scheduling to run specific days of month every 4hours

Tags: job-scheduling, autosys

I have a task to setup autosys job which runs every 4hours between 2nd to 8th of every month. I am new to autosys, Can someone please share their thoughts if this is possible? if yes, please share your knowledge on how to approach this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Job runs every 4 hours can be like:

```
start_times: "00:00, 04,00,08:00,12:00,16:00,20:00"
```

Regarding days of the month I advise you to create a calendar with the days because it is just from 2nd to 8th.

```
run_calendar: 123_calendar_example
```

Because you only can add rundays like below without date:

```
rundays: "mon,tu,th.."
```